# Presenting alternate fields based on a condition

Tags: php, sql

I want to present 4 fields from a table but the 4th field is based on a condition.

i.e. I want to present field1, field2, field3 and then either field4 or field5 where the choice of field5 would be based on a condition.

Is this possible?

I can present the table of field1, field2, field3 and field4 with no problem.

Comment: Do you want to encode the condition into the SQL or into the php code? Both are capable of handling that. It might also be helpful to [edit] the question to include a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    field1,
    field2,
    field3,
    CASE WHEN <some condition> THEN field4 ELSE field5 END AS other_field
FROM yourTable;
```

Or, you could use MySQL's `IF` function:

```
IF(<some condition>, field4, field) AS other_field
```

Comment: Yes, the IF statement worked fine.  Thank you very much.

Comment: The answer has helped me very much.  It says I am supposed to click on a green check mark to the right.  There is no green check mark anywhere on my screen, so I am sending this note to accept the answer and to close the thread.

Comment: Yes, I think I got it to work, the check mark is showing now and it is showing green.  
Thanks again.